# Execute package but [SQL Errm]ORA-20010/ETL Batch Process MYSCHEMA.FUND_PKG.LOAD_FUND failed. [Error Stack]ORA-20010: [ERROR] ETL Batch Process failed

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to execute a package which is source code so should have no errors since this runs consistently. I have made sure schema is correct and that data for parameters being passed are available by querying it, but am getting these errors that I don't know how to debug. Again, this package is source code which is ran consistently so there should not be any errors executing. I'm not sure if i'm not passing parameters correctly or what i'm doing wrong. These are the errors I'm getting:

> ORA-20010: [ERROR] ETL Batch Process MYSCHEMA.FUND_PKG.LOAD_FUND failed. Please check the CALL_STACK column in COMMON_LOG_ERROR_V view for further details.
> [Error Stack]
> ORA-20010: [ERROR] ETL Batch Process MYSCHEMA.FUND_PKG.LOAD_FUND failed. Please check the CALL_STACK column in COMMON_LOG_ERROR_V view for further details.
> ORA-06512: at "CDE_OPS.CMN_LOGGER_PKG", line 265
> ORA-06512: at "CDE_OPS.CMN_LOGGER_PKG", line 1799
> ORA-06512: at "CDE_STAGE.FUND_PKG", line 245
> [Back Trace]
> ORA-06512: at "CDE_OPS.CMN_LOGGER_PKG", line 265
> ORA-06512: at "CDE_OPS.CMN_LOGGER_PKG", line 1799
> ORA-06512: at "CDE_STAGE.FUND_PKG", line 245
> ORA-06512: at "CDE_STAGE.FUND_PKG", line 352

This is the package spec:

```
create or replace PACKAGE FUND_PKG
AS

    PROCEDURE LOAD_FUND (
      PV_JOB_ID            IN COMMON_BATCH_LOG.JOB_ID%TYPE,
      PV_JOB_NAME          IN COMMON_BATCH_LOG.JOB_NAME%TYPE,
      PV_STAGE_HANDLE      IN COMMON_BATCH_LOG.STAGE_HANDLE%TYPE,
      PV_CYCLE_DT          IN COMMON_BATCH_LOG.CYCLE_DT%TYPE,
      PV_CYCLE_ID          IN COMMON_BATCH_LOG.CYCLE_ID%TYPE,
      PV_SUB_CYCLE_ID      IN COMMON_BATCH_LOG.SUB_CYCLE_ID%TYPE,
      PV_CYCLE_TYPE_FREQ   IN COMMON_BATCH_LOG.CYCLE_TYPE_FREQ%TYPE,
      PV_SOURCE_CD         IN FUNDTABLE_SOURCE%TYPE,
      PV_VIEW_CD           IN FUNDTABLE_VIEWCODE%TYPE,
      PV_VIEW_NM           IN VARCHAR2
    );

END FUND_PKG;
```

I'm trying to execute the package using this code block:

```
DECLARE
  l_job_id            COMMON_BATCH_LOG.JOB_ID%TYPE;
  l_job_name          COMMON_BATCH_LOG.JOB_NAME%TYPE;
  l_stage_handle      COMMON_BATCH_LOG.STAGE_HANDLE%TYPE;
  l_cycle_dt          COMMON_BATCH_LOG.CYCLE_DT%TYPE;
  l_cycle_id          COMMON_BATCH_LOG.CYCLE_ID%TYPE;
  l_sub_cycle_id      COMMON_BATCH_LOG.SUB_CYCLE_ID%TYPE;
  l_cycle_type_freq   COMMON_BATCH_LOG.CYCLE_TYPE_FREQ%TYPE;
  l_source_cd         FUNDTABLE_SOURCE%TYPE;
  l_view_cd           FUNDTABLE_VIEWCODE%TYPE;
  l_view_nm           VARCHAR2(100) := 'PORTVIEW';

BEGIN
  MYSCHEMA.FUND_PKG.LOAD_FUND(
    PV_JOB_ID => '18323',
    PV_JOB_NAME => 'fund_job',
    PV_STAGE_HANDLE => '',
    PV_CYCLE_DT => TO_DATE('17-NOV-2021', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),
    PV_CYCLE_ID => 'DAILYCYCLE',
    PV_SUB_CYCLE_ID => 'INVEST',
    PV_CYCLE_TYPE_FREQ => 'D',
    PV_SOURCE_CD => 'CRYPTO',
    PV_VIEW_CD => 'NAT',
    PV_VIEW_NM => 'PORTVIEW'
  );
END;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *this package is source code*, or why you think there can never be runtime errors. However, the error stack mentions an error at CDE_STAGE.FUND_PKG line 245, so perhaps you could check what that line does, rather than showing us the package spec.

Answer (score 1):

This is error you got:

> [SQL Errm]**ORA-20010**: [ERROR] ETL Batch Process MYSCHEMA.FUND_PKG.LOAD_FUND failed. Please check the `CALL_STACK` column in `COMMON_LOG_ERROR_V` view for further details.

Bold information (**ORA-20010**) represents **user-defined exception**. Oracle reserved range from -20000 to -20999 for us, developers; -20010 is within that range so - yes, **developer** created that exception. Nice *feature* is that error also instructs you what to do:

```
select call_stack from common_log_error_v
```

If you don't know what that view contains, maybe you'd rather `select *` and - possibly - further restrict result set retrieved by that statement (i.e. include `where` clause, if necessary).

As we don't have your code nor access to your schema, it is more or less impossible for us to say much more about the issue.